# Iterating through two 2D lists to check if combination is possible

Tags: python, arrays

I am a bit in a issue here, dunno if I am using the correct thinking there but here I am.

I have two 2D arrays, one has a random variable populating its "second dimension" from a pool of letter from A to D and the other contains the **possible** combination, such as:

**random 2D list** note that the 2nd dimension i.e 'A', 'B', 'C' is randomly populated.

```
ran = [[51,'A'],[52,'D'],[53,'C'],[54,'B']]
```

**lookup 2D list with the possible combination**

```
lookup = [[51,'A'],[51,'B'],[52,'B'],[52,'C'],[52,'D'],[53,'A'],[54,'A'],[54,'B']]
```

Now, what I wanted to do was take the first items from the **random 2d list**, check if the combination is possible using the **lookup list**, *if it is* store it in a new list and then proceed with the other items, if not store in a BAD list :

**example**

```
[51,'A'] = possible, iterate through next number i.e 52. store in OK list
[52,'D'] = possible, store in OK list
[53,'C'] = not possible, store in BAD list
```

Not really sure if this makes sense at all, but thanks for any feedbacks provided!

Griffo.

Comment: What is the question? This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over the pairs in `ran`, you can use the [`in` operator](https://www.codingem.com/in-operator-in-python/#:%7E:text=Further%20Reading-,The%20%27in%27%20Operator%20in%20Python,It%20returns%20False%20if%20not.) to return a boolean indicating whether an identical pair is also present in `lookup`:

```
for r in ran:
  found = True if r in lookup else False
  print(r, found)
```

Given your 2 lists above, the output is

```
[51, 'A'] True
[52, 'D'] True
[53, 'C'] False
[54, 'B'] True
```